# Func<T, string> with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
                                         string param, Func<T, string> selector)
{
    return entity.Where(l =>
        System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, "%"), 
                                                            selector(l)) > 0);
}
```

I use it in the following way:

```
dbContext.ENTITY.MyMethod("%foo", f => f.SomeProp).ToList();
```

But how do I make `MyMethod` generic enough to handle any amount of properties on the `Func<T, string> selector` parameter?

I guess I could change the type to `List<Func<T, string>> selector` and iterate over it, but I suppose there is a better way?

Update:

Desired result when passing two paramters (for example):

```
dbContext.ENTITY.Where(l => 
    SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%foo", l.prop1) > 0 && 
    SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%bar%", l.prop2) > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Your selector parameter is a delegate; it doesn't have properties. Do you mean any number of parameters on the delegate? Or any number of type parameters to `MyMethod`? Or any number of selectors which is what `List<Func<T, string>> selector` would achieve?

Comment: @TimRogers Please have a look at my update. I made an example with two properties instead of one. I want to be able to pass any amount of properties to the `selector` parameter, to get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword to accept an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
                                         string param, 
                                         params Func<T, string>[] selectors)
{
    foreach(var selector in selectors)
    {
        entity = entity.Where(l => 
            SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, selector(l)) > 0);
    }

    return entity;
}
```

However, I doubt this will work as-is in Entity Framework. I think you'll need to use an `Expression<Func<T, string>>` which entity framework can translate SQL instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> entity, 
    string pattern, 
    params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] selectors)
{
    var method = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("PatIndex");
    foreach(var selector in selectors)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var call = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(pattern), selector);
        var gt = Expression.GreaterThan(call, Expression.Constant(0));
        var filter = Expression.Lamda(call, param);
        entity = entity.Where(filter);
    }

    return entity;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
dbContext.ENTITY.MyMethod("%foo", 
                          f => f.SomeProp1, 
                          f => f.SomeProp2, 
                          f => f.SomeProp3).ToList();
```

---

To use this with multiple `pattern` parameters as well, you can use a dictionary (I won't implement the method body, since it should be pretty obvious how to do that from the code above):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
    Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> filters)
{
    ...
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
dbContext.ENTITY.MyMethod(new Dictionary<string, Func<Entity, bool>>()
{
    { "%foo", l => l.Prop1 },
    { "%bar", l => l.Prop2 },
});
```

Alternatively you could use an array of tuples:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> entity, 
    string pattern, 
    params Tuple<string, Func<T, string>>[] filters)
{
    ...
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
dbContext.ENTITY.MyMethod(
    Tuple.Create("%foo", (Func<Entity, string>)(l => l.Prop1)),
    Tuple.Create("%bar", (Func<Entity, string>)(l => l.Prop2)));
```

Of course, you could also make your own custom class to wrap up these parameters so you don't have to repeatedly specify the delegate type.

The same techniques can just as easily be applied to the `IQueryable` solution that I listed above.

Comment: Looks great, but how do I pass the new `selectors` to `PatIndex`?

Comment: @Johan as *svick* points out, your original code won't. I'd like to help you but I'm not entirely sure what you want to happen inside this function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain AND in this case.

Comment: I made an update with an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't just invoke an `Expression`. Also, since the source collection is an `IEnumerable<T>`, this won't actually have any effect on the generated SQL.

Comment: The update does not match what the OP is seeking, which is to also pass different `string param` values. OP wants "%foo" with one selector and "%bar" with another.

Comment: Thanks! If I want more than one string parameter (like "%foo" above), is a `Dictionary<string, Func<T, string>[]>` the way to go? Right now I'm limited to one string.

Comment: @svick you're right. It should be fixed now (though I haven't tested it).

Comment: @Johan Correct. or if you want to go with the second method, use an `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, string>>>`.

Comment: Sigh... If I use my original code as an extension method, I get `This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.`. Any idea why? Works well when I run it without the extension...

Comment: @Johan Try my `IQueryable` solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change nothing and call your existing method like this:

```
dbContext.ENTITY
    .MyMethod("%foo", f => f.SomeProp)
    .MyMethod("%foo", f => f.AnotherProp)
    .MyMethod("%bar", b => b.SomethingElse)
    .ToList();
```

This is what you'd have to do inside your method that takes multiple selectors anyway (building up `Where`s in a loop).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entities, 
                                         string param, params Func<T, string>[] selectors)
{
    IEnumerable<T> results = entities;
    foreach(var selector in selectors)
    {
        results = results.Where(l -> …selector(l)…);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This does not work, however, when you want to associate different selectors with different `string param` arguments. In that case, you'd need to pass in an `IDictionary<string, Func<T,string>>` (one selector per param) or an `ILookup<string, Func<T,string>>` (one or more selectors per param).

At this point, the code will start to look pretty gnarly as you must build up a dictionary before each invocation of the extension method, so the first option becomes more appealing for its clarity and relative brevity.

Comment: Yea, that was my plan B :)

Comment: @Johan The second part of my answer shows how you'd build up ANDs using sequential `Where` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking into combining expressions, you can do it trough PredicateBuilder - i.e.:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, string param, params Func<T, string>[] selectors) {
    var expression = PredicateBuilder.Make<T>(t => true);
    foreach(var selector in selectors) {
      expression = PredicateBuilder.And<T>(expression,
        l =>
        System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, "%", selector(l)) > 0);
    }

    return entity.AsQueryable().Where(expression).AsEnumerable();
 }

public static class PredicateBuilder {
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Make<T>() {
    return null;
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Make<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    return predicate;
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr, Expression<Func<T, bool>> orExpression) {
    if (expr == null) {
      return orExpression;
    }
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(orExpression, expr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(expr.Body, invokedExpr), expr.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr, Expression<Func<T, bool>> andExpression) {
    if (expr == null) {
      return andExpression;
    }
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(andExpression, expr.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(expr.Body, invokedExpr), expr.Parameters);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question and then stumbled on an even better answer that's available nowadays. You can pass in a tuple with your parameters on it. Especially now that we have named tuples available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples